# How To Evaluate Status of Checkbox on Button Click JQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Should be a pretty basic concept but, for some reason, this is giving me a hard time. The question should be pretty self-explanatory from the title. I am trying to get the status when a button is clicked. Here is the form I am referencing:

```
<form id="setupForm">
    <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name"><br/>

    <label>Tag</label>
        <input type="text" name="Tag"><br/>

    <label>Choose Your Theme</label>
        <input type="radio" name="theme" value="1"> 1
        <input type="radio" name="theme" value="2"> 2
        <input type="radio" name="theme" value="3"> 3<br/>

    <label>Choose Your Pre-Built Pages</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="page" value="About" checked>About Us
        <input type="checkbox" name="page" value="Contact" checked>Contact Us
        <input type="checkbox" name="page" value="Terms" checked>Terms of Service
        <input type="checkbox" name="page" value="Privacy" checked>Privacy Policy<br/>

    <label>Insert YouTube Embed Code (Not Required)</label>
        <input type="text" name="embed"><br/>

    <button id="proceedBtn" type="button">Proceed</button><br>

</form>
```

When `proceedBtn` is clicked I need to check and see which of the four checkboxes with the name of `page` is or is not checked. I'm trying to get a `boolean` response here.

I have tried:

```
var sitePageAbout = $('input[name=pageAbout]');
if(sitePageAbout.prop('checked')){
    valueString += "true,";
}else{
    valueString += "false,";
    console.log(valueString);

}

//#2

var sitePageAbout = $('input[name=pageAbout]');
if(sitePageAbout.attr('checked')){
    valueString += "true,";
}else{
    valueString += "false,";
}
//#3

var sitePageAbout = $('input[name=pageAbout]');
if(sitePageAbout.is(':checked')){
    valueString += "true,";
}else{
    valueString += "false,";
}
```

They ALL return `true`

**I have also tried:**

1. Removing the `checked` attribute from the checkboxes --> Returned `true`.
2. Changed `checked` value to `false` --> Returned `true`

It seems like it either returns `true` or `undefined`... any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I can't see an input element with `name=pageAbout` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you need this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#proceedBtn").click(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      console.log($(this).val() + '  is checked');
    }else{
      console.log($(this).val() + '  is not checked');
    }
  });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="setupForm">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="Name"><br/>
<label>Tag</label>
<input type="text" name="Tag"><br/>
<label>Choose Your Theme</label>
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="1"> 1
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="2"> 2
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="3"> 3<br/>
<label>Choose Your Pre-Built Pages</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="page" value="About" checked>About Us
<input type="checkbox" name="page" value="Contact" checked>Contact Us
<input type="checkbox" name="page" value="Terms" checked>Terms of Service
<input type="checkbox" name="page" value="Privacy" checked>Privacy Policy<br/>
<label>Insert YouTube Embed Code (Not Required)</label>
<input type="text" name="embed"><br/>
<button id="proceedBtn" type="button">Proceed</button><br>
</form>
```

Comment: To be honest each of the inputs have a different name. I took the middle section of your code, i.e. `$("input[name=page]").each(function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
     console.log($(this).val() + " is checked");
    }else{
      console.log($(this).val() + " is not checked");
    }` and ran it, but nothing printed to console, regardless of the checkbox state.

Comment: I was able to get it to print, but it is still always `checked`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#proceedBtn").click(function() {
  var valueString = '';
  $('input[name=page]').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      console.log($(this).val() + '  is checked');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="setupForm">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="Name"><br/>
  <label>Tag</label>
  <input type="text" name="Tag"><br/>
  <label>Choose Your Theme</label>
  <input type="radio" name="theme" value="1"> 1
  <input type="radio" name="theme" value="2"> 2
  <input type="radio" name="theme" value="3"> 3<br/>
  <label>Choose Your Pre-Built Pages</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="page" value="About" checked>About Us
  <input type="checkbox" name="page" value="Contact" checked>Contact Us
  <input type="checkbox" name="page" value="Terms" checked>Terms of Service
  <input type="checkbox" name="page" value="Privacy" checked>Privacy Policy<br/>
  <label>Insert YouTube Embed Code (Not Required)</label>
  <input type="text" name="embed"><br/>
  <button id="proceedBtn" type="button">Proceed</button><br>
</form>
```